# Convert to datetimeoffset from SQL query to local time based on TimeZoneInfo

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, timezone, timezone-offset

For whatever silly reason, I remain confused when dealing with Timezones.

When a record is created, I use:

```
getutcdate()
```

So for example, it's stored in a datetimeoffset column and looks like this:

```
2015-07-03 20:44:21.0300000 +00:00
```

So no offset, just raw UTC.

Now, in server code, I want to do a few things... I have a query that gets me just the CreatedDate for articles posted for a particular user. I'm storing this in a datatable:

```
Dim tz as TimeZoneInfo = GetUserTZInfo(User)
Dim dt as DataTable = GetArticleDates(User)
Dim MaxArticles As Integer = 5
Dim PostedThisMonth As Integer
Dim Remaining As Integer
```

I'm limited the user to 5 articles posted per/month, so you can see where time can get shaky toward the beginning or end of the month based on the user's timezone. It's tomorrow somewhere, yet same moment in time everywhere.

But I want it to be user-friendly and just base it on the user, not server time.

I'm having difficulties using some of the examples on converting to local times because of my datatype of **datetimeoffset**

Could anyone suggest a best practice/method on how to achieve the following:

1. Search the **dt** for any created dates that are equal to the user's month.
2. Generate count for PostedThisMonth based on what's found.

The only sticky area like I said is at the beginning or end of the month... basically that 12 hour window, and then of course DST, but I'm less concerned with that.

Comment: Just use date math and adjust it based on the users timezone. You have the users timezone somewhere?

Comment: @SeanLange I do. The example function I showed you returns a TimeZoneInfo object for the user.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this in the database? Otherwise you have to return all the info and then filter it down. Would be more efficient to only return the data you want in the first place.

Comment: No offsets are stored in the database. Technically I'm just querying the top 5 desc so the query is small, but for example, if it's close to midnight at the end of the month, for some, its already the next month, although same moment in time for everyone. Gosh this gets confusing.

Comment: So how do you know what offset to use for a given user? You seem to be making this harder on yourself than it really is. If the users offset if +5 then you just need to add 5 hours to the stored date to get that same time range based on their offset.

Comment: @SeanLange You're right, I am making it harder on myself and I was attempting to do exactly what you just posted. Found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Honestly I think this comes down to my mental block over timezones in general. For whatever reason, my head just locks up.

Comment: Yes that is pretty close. The only change I would make is to leverage the timezoneoffset object to help you limit the return from the database.

Comment: you havent answered how you get the offset to use for a given user.  Is the app hosted at the client?

Comment: @user5103147 They select their timezone on sign-up.

Comment: and this is stored in the database?  is it stored like `-6` `-4.5` and such?

Comment: @user5103147 Actually no, it's stored as the TimeZone ID.

Comment: Using `TimeZoneInfo` and storing the ID is the correct way.  @user5103147 and @SeanLange are incorrect.  Do not store a plain numeric offset or just add/subtract it yourself.  Refer to "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you're ahead of most folks.  You're doing it right by storing UTC times in your database and tracking the user's time zone with `TimeZoneInfo`.

If you never deviate from +00:00, you *could* store juse a `datetime` or `datetime2` instead of a `datetimeoffset`, but it doesn't hurt anything and it has the added benefit of being unambiguously UTC.

All you really need to do is:

- Use the user's time zone to convert the start and end of the user's local month to their equivalent UTC points in time.
- Query your database using that range of values.

  ```
  // compute the start of this month and the next month, by the user's time zone
  Dim today As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz).Date
  Dim startDateOfThisMonth As DateTime = New DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1)
  Dim startDateOfNextMonth As DateTime = startDateOfThisMonth.AddMonths(1)

  // convert those to UTC
  Dim startUtc As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startDateOfThisMonth, tz)
  Dim endUtc As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startDateOfNextMonth, tz)
  ```

  Or, since you're using `datetimeoffset` in your database, you could just build a `DateTimeOffset` in the last step. SQL will use the offset to convert to UTC internally when scanning the index.

  ```
  Dim start As DateTimeOffset = New DateTimeOffset(startDateOfThisMonth,
                                          tz.GetUtcOffset(startDateOfThisMonth))
  Dim end As DateTimeOffset = New DateTimeOffset(startDateOfNextMonth,
                                          tz.GetUtcOffset(startDateOfNextMonth))
  ```

When you query your database, use `table.dto >= @start AND table.dto < @end` (a half-open interval).

Comment: Very cool and interesting approach. Thank you for chiming in. Trying this now. I had it all working, but it was still slightly cumbersome and expensive.

Comment: This is fantastic.. So just to be totally clear, if I pass a Start and/or End with a positive or negative offset, SQL Server will take care of it regardless? This seems to be working but just wanted to be sure. Thank you so much.

Comment: If your field is a `datetimeoffset`, and your query parameter is also a `DateTimeOffset`, then yes - SQL will normalize it to UTC during the query process.  Otherwise, you would convert to UTC yourself first.  You can still do that yourself if you like, or if you just don't trust SQL to do it. ;)